# Узнать количество GDI дескрипторов под Wine

Tags: linux, gdi, wine

Имеется Linux, в котором под Wine запускается графическое приложение на делфях. Есть подозрение, что оно падает из-за превышение лимита дескрипторов.
Можно ли как-то отследить их количество, выделяемых приложению?

P.S.Под Windows можно программно посмотреть их кол-во

Comment: *Под Windows можно программно посмотреть их кол-во* — а что мешает сделать то же самое под wine-ом?

Comment: там функции WinApi возвращают 0 вместо кол-ва...